# Regular Expression data annotation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want my password to contain atleast 1 uppercase letter, 1 digit and 1 special symbol accordingly I created this expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain atleast 1 digit, 1 capital letter and atleast 1 one of symbols from -+_!@#$%^&*.,?")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

But whatever I enter it gives the error message. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> The regular expression searches for an exact match, not using `^` before and `$` at the end of the pattern produces the same results as using it. For a search hit, prepend and append the pattern with `.*`.

You should add `.*` at the end to make the exact match working.

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]).*", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain atleast 1 digit, 1 capital letter and atleast 1 one of symbols from -+_!@#$%^&*.,?")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/USd027)